# Why use UML for embedded systems?

Tags: uml

Most of the embedded systems applications are written in C, i.e non-OOPs. But UML is designed for OO. So my question is why people advocate and use UML for embedded systems (and real time embedded systems)  ?

Answer (score 4):

UML is not just class diagrams, it includes state diagrams and flowcharts, which are useful also outside of an object oriented setting.

Also, many C programs are written in a way that borrows a few concepts from OOP.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Could you please give a couple of examples on concepts where we use some features of oops in our C program?

Comment: For example, if you have a struct Order { ... } and functions like applyDiscount (struct Order o, float discountPercentage), then you could model this as a class "Order" in UML with the struct members as its attributes and the functions like applyDiscount as its operations.